# Взаимодействие между элементами списка ListView

Tags: android, listview

Есть список, в котором в каждом элементе есть OnClickListener,  т.е.  при нажатии на элемент в item всплывает кнопка и что бы она скрылась нужно нажать на нее повторно. Я же хочу сделать так что бы если в одном item кнопка появилась после чего если нажать на следующий item в нем тоже всплывет кнопка, но при этом кнопка в предыдущем item должна скрыться, как такую схему можно реализовать?

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private static final String TAG = "ContactListAdapter";

    private ArrayList<String> list;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


    public ContactListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> contactList) {
        this.context = context;
        list = contactList;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        private View rootView;
        private TextView tvName;
        private TextView tvInitials;
        private ImageView ivAvatart;
        private ImageView ivStatus;

        private String contactName;
        private boolean isShow;

        private ViewHolder preHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;


        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.rootView = convertView;
            holder.contactName = (String) getItem(position);


            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            holder.rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_contact_list_item, null);


            holder.tvName = (TextView) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_contact_name);
            holder.tvInitials = (TextView) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_contact_initials);
            holder.ivAvatart = (ImageView) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_contact_avatar);
            holder.ivStatus = (ImageView) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_status);

            holder.tvName.setText(holder.contactName);
            setIcons(position, holder);

            holder.rootView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.isShow = false;

        /**-------------Item listener---------------**/

        holder.relativeLayoutParent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.preHolder != null) {
                int buttonTranslation = holder.timeoutButtonContainer.getLayoutParams().width;

                holder.relativeLayoutMain
                        .animate()
                        .translationX(0)
                        .setDuration(350);
                holder.timeoutButtonContainer
                        .animate()
                        .translationX(buttonTranslation)
                        .setDuration(350);

                holder.isShow = false;

            } else {
                int buttonTranslation = - holder.timeoutButtonContainer.getLayoutParams().width + 2;

                holder.relativeLayoutMain
                        .animate()
                        .translationX(buttonTranslation)
                        .setDuration(350);
                holder.timeoutButtonContainer
                        .animate()
                        .translationX(buttonTranslation)
                        .setDuration(350);

                holder.isShow = true;

                holder.preHolder = holder;
                }
            }
        });


        return holder.rootView;

    }
}
```

**UDT:**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;


    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.rootView = convertView;
        holder.contactName = (String) getItem(position);


        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        holder.rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_contact_list_item, null);


        holder.tvName = (TextView) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_contact_name);
        holder.tvInitials = (TextView) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_contact_initials);
        holder.ivAvatart = (ImageView) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_contact_avatar);
        holder.ivStatus = (ImageView) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_status);

        holder.tvName.setText(holder.contactName);
        setIcons(position, holder);

        if (currentItem == position) {
            holder.isShow = false;
        }

        //        holder.isShow = false;

        holder.rootView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    /**-------------Item listener---------------**/

    holder.relativeLayoutParent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.isShow) {

                currentItem = position;
                int buttonTranslation = holder.timeoutButtonContainer.getLayoutParams().width;


                holder.relativeLayoutMain
                        .animate()
                        .translationX(0)
                        .setDuration(350);
                holder.timeoutButtonContainer
                        .animate()
                        .translationX(buttonTranslation)
                        .setDuration(350);

                holder.isShow = false;
                //notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                int buttonTranslation = -holder.timeoutButtonContainer.getLayoutParams().width + 2;

                holder.relativeLayoutMain
                        .animate()
                        .translationX(buttonTranslation)
                        .setDuration(350);
                holder.timeoutButtonContainer
                        .animate()
                        .translationX(buttonTranslation)
                        .setDuration(350);

                holder.isShow = true;
                //notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
    });


    return holder.rootView;

}


    return holder.rootView;

}
```

**UDT 2:**

```
if (preHolder != null) {
                int buttonTranslation = preHolder.timeoutButtonContainer.getLayoutParams().width;

                preHolder.relativeLayoutMain
                        .animate()
                        .translationX(0)
                        .setDuration(350);
                preHolder.timeoutButtonContainer
                        .animate()
                        .translationX(buttonTranslation)
                        .setDuration(350);

                preHolder.isShow = false;

            } else {
                int buttonTranslation = - holder.timeoutButtonContainer.getLayoutParams().width + 2;

                holder.relativeLayoutMain
                        .animate()
                        .translationX(buttonTranslation)
                        .setDuration(350);
                holder.timeoutButtonContainer
                        .animate()
                        .translationX(buttonTranslation)
                        .setDuration(350);

                holder.isShow = true;

                preHolder = holder;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `holder.relativeLayoutParent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {` необходимо изменить логику. Сейчас обрабатывается только элемент, который нажимается.

Вам же необходимо один из вариантов:

1. Запоминать предыдущий открытый и при нажатии на другой, закрывать его.
2. При нажатии проходить по всем и закрывать их все, а необходимый открыть.

Comment: Логику я понял, но как это можно реализовать, я пока не совсем понимаю каким образом можно связать элементы в адаптере?

Comment: попробовал  сделать так как вы сказали, но не сработало, возможно я что то  напутал,  я обновил код адаптера, гляньте пожалуйста!

Comment: Попробовал таким способом, функцию свою оно выполняет, но почему то только один раз, после него вообще не реагирует на нажатия

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36460/discussion-between-vandrj-and-kirill-stoianov).

Answer (score 2):

1. Создайте в адаптере `int` хранящий позицию нажатого элемента в списке.
2. При нажатии это значение задавайте равным позиции нажатого элемента.
3. После нажатия перерисовывайте адаптер вызовом его метода `notifyDataSetChanged()`
4. В `getView` адаптера устанавливаете нажатость/ненажатость элемента, проверяя совпадение его позиции со значением переменной из п.1.

Comment: попробовал вашим способом, обновил код в вопросе, в общем с использованием notifyDataSetChanged()  твориться в списке вообще странное, при нажатии нету анимации  и все элементы превращаются в элемент ( который в списке идет последним), ну и проблему с закрытием это не решило